# ASP.NET exception "Thread was being aborted" causes method to exit

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

In the code below, sometimes `someFunctionCall()` generates an exception:

> Thread was being aborted.

How come the code in code Block B never runs? Does ASP.NET start a new thread for each method call? I was suprised to see that when this exception happens the code in Block B never runs, the method returns, and my application keeps running. Can someone please explain this?

```
public void method()
{
     // CODE BLOCK A
     //...    

     try 
     {
         someFunctionCall(); // this call is generating thread abort exception
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
         // log exception message
     }

    // CODE BLOCK B
    // ...    
}
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is a `ThreadAbortException`; it's a special exception that is automatically rethrown at the end of every catch block, unless you call `Thread.ResetAbort()`.

ASP .Net methods like `Response.End` or `Response.Redirect` (unless you pass `false`) throw this exception to end processing of the current page; your `someFunctionCall()` is probably calling one of those methods.

ASP .Net itself handles this exception and calls `ResetAbort` to continue processing.

Comment: So how could i get it to ignore that exception and continue executing the code in block B?

Comment: Are you sure you want to?
If someFunctionCall is redirecting or ending the response, you probably shouldn't continue it

Comment: What does someFunctionCall do?

Comment: It makes a XML-RPC call to 3rd party vendor. No response end or redirct. If it is an older version of the XML-RPC API I would like to ignore it and continue with default values.

Comment: Call Thread.ResetAbort in the catch block.  Also, ask the vendor what the exception is from.  What's the exception's stack trace?

Comment: Thanks SLaks, appreciate the help. I will try that.

Comment: @Aaron: What are you talking about?

Comment: As @SLaks mentioned:`catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
{
   System.Threading.Thread.ResetAbort();
}`

Comment: Calling Thread.ResertAbort() inside catch block did not work for me.
It still exited :(

Answer (score 3):

To work around this problem, use one of the following methods:
For `Response.End`, call the `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest` method instead of `Response.End` to bypass the code execution to the `Application_EndRequest` event.

For `Response.Redirect`, use an overload, `Response.Redirect(String url, bool endResponse)` that passes false for the `endResponse` parameter to suppress the internal call to `Response.End`. For example:

```
Response.Redirect ("nextpage.aspx", false);
```

If you use this workaround, the code that follows `Response.Redirect` is executed.
For `Server.Transfer`, use the `Server.Execute` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is increasing the "Idle Time-out (minutes)" property for the Application Pool on IIS.

I set it to "43200" which is the max value.

I also adjusted the recycling settings ...

Answer (score -2):

Try this way :

**This is my extension method :**

```
 public static void WriteJSONObject(this HttpResponse response, object content) {
            response.ContentType = "application/json";
            response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(content));
            response.End();

 }
```

**And the logic :**

```
public void RegisterUser() {
    try {
        Response.WriteJSONObject(new { Result = "See hello" });
    } 
    catch (Exception err) {
        if (err.Message != "Thread was being aborted.")
            Response.WriteJSONObject(new { Result = err.Message });
        else {
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is wrong.  You should _never_ compare an exception's `Message` to a hard-coded string.  Instead, you can write `catch (ThreadAbortException) {} catch (Exception ex) { ... }`.  Also, there's no point in calling `Response.End` if there's already a `ThreadAbortException`.

Comment: P.s : The solutions above didn't work for me like most people. No matter what I did didn't work so this is the only solution I've found and works just fine.

Comment: I wasn't saying that it won't work; I'm saying that it's a horrible idea.  Your code is solving a different problem that has nothing to do with this question.