# Error when execute Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a following error when
 `Response.End();`
 is execute.
[image]

Its look like a `threading error` but unable to handle it.Any body know about the error and how to fix it?.I am using `VS2008`.Thanks.

Comment: Please Explain What you trying to do .??

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014439/asp-net-exception-thread-was-being-aborted-causes-method-to-exit . Your problems might not be the same, but I think the answer will help you as well. Or even better, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476/why-is-my-asp-net-application-throwing-threadabortexception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to explicitly call Response.End()? You can call [HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629) to get around this issue, but you may want to consider refactoring your code to not prematurely end the response.

Comment: Unrelated, but - IMO, response.end is perfectly useful; what he should stay away from are try-catch blocks, period. With few exceptions, there should be only one in the whole app: global app handler, and only to log it (use built-in mechanism for showing error page).

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be expected behavior.  You are telling the server to stop processing the page.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx