# Error: Excepiton in System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

While downloading template i m getting following error message.

I have tried instead of  Response.Flush(); with Response.End();. But getting same error.

```
Error: Excepiton in Download:System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
```

Any idea to avoid above exception

Code

```
private void DownloadFile(string filePath, string downloadFileName)
{
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + downloadFileName);
    Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
    // Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Avoid Response.End() "Thread was being aborted" Exception during the Excel file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce)

Comment: Well, that's kind of what `Response.End` does. If that's not what you intended, you probably have to review the design of your application - most likely, you're doing some serious spaghetti in your request structure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As answered here :- [How to Avoid Response.End() "Thread was being aborted" Exception during the Excel file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988445/how-to-avoid-response-end-thread-was-being-aborted-exception-during-the-exce)

> Replace this : `HttpContext.Current.Response.End();`
>
> With this :

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush(); // Sends all currently buffered output to the client.
HttpContext.Current.Response.SuppressContent = true;  // Gets or sets a value indicating whether to send HTTP content to the client.
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); // Causes ASP.NET to bypass all events and filtering in the HTTP pipeline**
```

> chain of execution and directly execute the EndRequest event.

And answered here :- [ASP.NET exception "Thread was being aborted" causes method to exit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014439/asp-net-exception-thread-was-being-aborted-causes-method-to-exit)

> This is a ThreadAbortException; it's a special exception that is
>   automatically rethrown at the end of every catch block, unless you
>   call Thread.ResetAbort().
>
> ASP .Net methods like Response.End or Response.Redirect (unless you
>   pass false) throw this exception to end processing of the current
>   page; your someFunctionCall() is probably calling one of those
>   methods.
>
> ASP .Net itself handles this exception and calls ResetAbort to
>   continue processing.

Comment: Thank you for answer :)